# List from map wont appear in my ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, google-cloud-firestore

I made a list of values from a map retrieved from firestore database. The problem is that it won't appear on my `listView`. I initiated another list from another map and it appeared in my `listView`. Why is the list from the map retrieved from firestore document won't work while other list works fine?

```
public class RecipeActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<Object> arrayAdapter;
private FirebaseFirestore newRecipeDb;
private Map<String, Object> meMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<> ();
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

    textView = findViewById(R.id. breadRecipe);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, list);

    newRecipeDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    newRecipeDb.collection("users")
            .document("bakeryMgt")
            .collection("New Recipe")
            .document("cherri pie")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            System.out.println("DocumentSnapshot data " + document.getData());
                            meMap = document.getData();
                            list = new ArrayList<Object>(meMap.values());
                            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No such document");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("get failed with " + task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: After calling `setAdapter` you should call `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCreate` you're creating an `ArrayAdapter` based on `list`:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, list);
```

Then inside `onComplete`, you create a new list:

```
 list = new ArrayList<Object>(meMap.values());
```

This means that the `arrayAdapter` is not pointing to the `list` that you put the data into.

The solution is to add the data from the document to the existing `list`:

```
list.add(meMap.values());
```

I'd also recommend tying the adapter to the list view when you initialize both:

```
listView = findViewById(R.id.listIngredient);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, list);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

And then only notify the adapter that its data changed, once you add an item to the `list`:

```
list.add(meMap.values());
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I now get why nothing was displayed to the listView, as the adapter is pointing to the wrong list. Using list.add(meMap.values()) adds the entire list as single item in the listView where it is supposed to display each value as a single item in the view. How can I add the list of values from meMap.values() just like a normal list in the listView?

Comment: Something like this: `for (Object value: meMap.values()) { list.add(value); }`